# Is there a way to copy data from a three column list into a different sheet based on the values in one of the columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I have am creating budget spreadsheet that has a summary of the amounts remaining in each category in the first tab
[screenshot of the budget tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kikPY.png)

I would like to make a macro that takes all those values and copies them into a different tab for tracking purposes. The new tab has the date, paycheck amount and each category in the first row, and the values should be copied in the rows following. If someone changes the order of the categories, I would like the macro to still find the correct column and paste it there. Likewise, if someone were to add a new category, I would like the macro to add that category to the first blank column.

Here is what the tracking sheet looks like
[screenshot of the budget tracking sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Els0K.png)

So far I have written this code and have noted where it stops working.

```js
function rollover1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cb = ss.getSheetByName('Current Budget');
  var bt = ss.getSheetByName('Budget Tracking');
  var btlr = bt.getLastRow()+1;
  //copy over date and paycheck value
  bt.getRange(btlr,1).setValue(cb.getRange('C3').getValue());
  bt.getRange(btlr,2).setValue(cb.getRange('C4').getValue());
  //get number of areas
  var numareas = (ss.getRange('B6').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow()-6);
  //search each budget area and paste value for period, this is where it stops working
  var id, blank, amt;
  var areas = cb.getRange(6,1,numareas,3).getValues();
  [id] = areas[0];
  [blank] = areas[1];
  [amt] = areas[2];
  blank = Number(blank.split(" ")[1]);
  var ids = bt.getRange("A1:AEP1").getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<ids[0].length; i++) {
    if (ids[0][i] == id) {
      bt.getRange(bt.getLastRow() + 1, i + 1, 1, 2).setValues([[id,amt]]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The short answer to your question is yes.  However, if you want an example you will have to provide more information because it's hard to figure out what you're trying to accomplish from the code you have provided.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the logic for achieving your goal. And also, I cannot understand the current issue of your script from `So far I have written this code and have noted where it stops working.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, About `screenshot of the budget tab`, I cannot see the column and row numbers. How about this?